# Two windows entries in the GRUB list

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

everyone. I am not new to ubuntu environment but I use it as a secondary os. Recently, I had to reinstall ubuntu as dual partition to my windows. When I try to customize my grub order,  I noticed two windows paths, and both directs to windows installation. Even though both paths doesn't do any harm to my computer,  I want to know which I should remove?.  I just don't want to go through the grub rescue again.

Since this is my first post here, I couldn't post a pic here, the link for imgur is ==>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cROo3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the second entry for Windows.  That seems to be the default entry, but the first one seems to be a custom overwrite.  Just delete the second Windows Bootloader entry and give it a shot.